# Convert from image to Base64 string responds very slow in Javascript or Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

I want to convert Image file to base64 string in typescript
but this process very slow

```
base64Media = '';
uploadFile(fileItem: FilePreviewModel): Observable<any> {
 const reader = new FileReader();
 reader.onloadend = () => {
  this.base64Media = reader.result;
 }
 reader.readAsDataURL(fileItem.file);
 return this.api.upload({this.base64Media});
}
```

base64Media variable goes to the backend service but its value is null. I also tried Promise but it still doesn't work

Comment: `this.base64Media = reader.result;` is in the future when `return this.api.upload({this.base64Media});` executes. You cannot access `this.base64Media` except from inside `onloadend`.

Comment: Just upload the file, don't convert it to `base64`

Comment: @Amadan but this.base64Media outside the function created and it is global variable

Comment: @AlekseyL.backend service reject other types

Comment: Global variable or not (BTW, it's an instance variable, not a global variable, unless `this` is `global` or `window`), it's beside the point. The point is, it is _not assigned yet_. Imagine you tell your friend to go buy some snacks, then immediately try to take the snacks from him before he leaves your house. Whether he wants to give you the snacks or not is not the point; the point is _he hasn't bought them yet_. You have to wait. `onloadend` will execute at the time he has snacks. A time machine hasn't been invented yet, snacks can't be sent from the future back to when you wanted them.

Comment: you are right, however i don't know how can i solve this problem. @Amadan

Comment: As I said, move the upload into `onloadend`. I do not know what `this.api.upload` returns, or if you need that to be returned from `uploadFile`; the specific solution kind of depends on whether or not you need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thare are multiple async callbacks that happen. The first is the uploadevent, the second "load" of the complete data.

```js
      const reader = new FileReader();
      // happens async
      reader.onload = (e: ProgressEvent) => {
        const image = new Image();
        image.src = (e.target as FileReader).result as string;

        image.onload = (event: Event) => {
          const imgBase64Path = (e.target as FileReader).result as string;
          this.base64Media = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(imgBase64Path);
          //only when this point is reached the data is there. 
        };

    };
    // this triggers a async call
    reader.readAsDataURL((uploadEvent.target as HTMLInputElement).files[0]);

    // this will be executed instantly after, but won't wait of async execution. 
    // this api call should be inside the "image onload"- part above. 

    return this.api.upload({this.base64Media})
```

what you could do is use a "observable" to pass the data in wich triggers a callback.

Or put the api call inside the onload-Callback.

But it depends on what you want to retun.